# How to show the remaining cells on the UIButton click at the bottom of the UITableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uibutton

I have a list of ATM counters to be shown in a table view. But initially i am showing the nearest ATM centre i.e single ATM centre at the first row. At the bottom of the first UITablecell there is a UIButton to show the show the remaining ATM centres.

My question is "How to show the remaining table cells on that UIButton Click". 
Please have an idea on this.

Comment: Are you referring to something similar to accordion. Like expandable/collapsible cells ?

Comment: Yes Ofcourse i am looking for it.. actually there are 10 counters in total. So initially i am displaying only first counters. Below there is a button "Show all counters". On clicking it the rest of the counters should be shown.

Comment: First you need to search on google, there are so many tuts , demos, stack answers are available. First read them and check did they fulfil your need if no then post question. Take ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to display single cell initially.

- Customize the view similar to cell and load it on section.
- Provide button tag as section.
- On Button click you can reload cells for selected section by button tag.

If it is not single cell

- Use the similar approach and identify based on selected section.

Refer to Expandable Table view

- [Objective C](https://github.com/jackkwok/JKExpandTableView)
- [Swift](https://github.com/appcoda/expandable-table-view)

Comment: Please a github project will help me though

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: i need it in swift :) please help

Comment: Updated Swift GitHub reference.